# PopUpWindow badTokenException

Tags: android, popupwindow

I had this problem.

> Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity
>   running? Fatal Exception: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException

I try to solve it by code bellow:

```
findViewById(R.id.root_view)
.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {   

       updatePopup();

}});
```

...

```
private void updatePopup(final String link) {

    final View popUpView = LayoutInflater.from(Splash.this).inflate(R.layout.update_popup, null);
    final PopupWindow mpopup = new PopupWindow(popUpView, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, true);

   //...

    mpopup.showAtLocation(popUpView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    mpopup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    mpopup.setTouchable(true);
    mpopup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    mpopup.setAnimationStyle(android.R.style.Animation_Dialog);

}
```

But still, I get this error sometimes.

What should I do?

Comment: `if(!((Activity) context).isFinishing())` then use `mpopup.showAtLocation` and other methods. Your activity has been finished or destroyed that's why you are getting this above issue.